# How do I identify unique properties of elements within my array?

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say I work at the Dept. of Health.  I've processed food poisoning complaints and stored the complaints data into a multi-dimensional array like so:

1. ID - 5 digit ID number for the restaurant victim ate at
2. Date - Date of Food Poisoning
3. Name - Name of Victim
4. Age - Age of Victim
5. Phone - Victim's Phone Number

Array[0] contains the first complaint's data.  Array[0].ID contains the restaurant ID of the first complaint and so forth.

Within my array how do I extract a list of **unique** 5 digit IDs?

Some restaurants might have 50 complaints and some might have just 1.  I want to create a list of all of the **unique** restaurant IDs that show up in my complaints data.

```
var Unique = array.ID.Distinct();
```

does not work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "does not work" bs.  "does not compile" truth.

Comment: Please, avoid "this does not work" issues.

Comment: ok, someone please explain the "issues".  Will is clearly upset with my choice of words.

Comment: There are code smells in code, and there are homework smells in SO

Comment: You should always say _why_ it doesn't work, e.g. what compiler errors or runtime exceptions you get, or the input, expected, and actual results if it runs but with incorrect results.

Comment: @paqogomez What are code smells?  I assure you I am not a student and this isn't homework.  I am a novice picking up programming to the extent it's needed to get results in my work.

Comment: Sorry to give you a bad time @phan.  :) only teasing.  [Code smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) is code that you look at that just "feels" wrong.

Comment: Is this actually a multi-dimensional array or is it an array of objects? You've supplied conflicting information.

Comment: @paqogomez Ok, I can smile and take a joke then.  I thought I was running into an angry, chippy programmer who takes issue with my admittedly novice questions.

Comment: @canon Thanks for pointing that out.  To be more precise, it is an array of objects.  Being new to this, it's hard to meet the level of precision in communication/writing that is required of me and expected by programmers like you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) first...

```
var ids = array.Select(o => o.ID).Distinct();
```

**Edit:**

> Hi, can you please explain why.

First, let's talk about what you did wrong:

```
var ids = array.ID.Distinct();
```

1. You tried to refer to `ID`, a non-existent member of the *array*. What you're looking for is the `ID` of an *item* within the array.
2. You tried to call `Distinct()` on that non-existent member rather than the *collection*.

Now let's look at what the new code does:

```
var ids = array.Select(o => o.ID).Distinct();
```

That `Select()` generates a new enumerable yielding only the `ID` values. The `Distinct()` generates *another* enumerable, yielding only the unique values from the `Select()`.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain why.  Was it harder to implement without c# and linq?

Comment: @Phan, I've updated my answer. Outside of that, if you're not going to use `C#`, what language are we talking about? This can certainly be done without linq... it's just more code you'll have to write.

Comment: @canon Thank you for the in-depth explanation.  It is super helpful for me, probably more than you realize.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `HashSet` if you plan to do lookups going forward:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(array.Select(i => i.ID));
```

This will automatically remove duplicates and also allow near O(1) lookups.